# sqlite selecting multiple tables

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a database in sqlite with c.300 tables. Currently i am iterating through a list and appending the data.

Is there a faster way / more pythonic way of doing this?

```
df = []
for i in Ave.columns:
    try:
        df2 = get_mcap(i)
        df.append(df2)
        #print (i)
    except:
        pass
df = pd.concat(df, axis=0
```

Ave is a dataframe where the column in the list i want to iterate through.

```
def get_mcap(Ticker):
    cnx = sqlite3.connect('Market_Cap.db')
    df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM '%s'"%(Ticker), cnx)
    df.columns = ['Date', 'Mcap-Ave', 'Mcap-High', 'Mcap-Low']
    df = df.set_index('Date')
    df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
    cnx.close
    return df
```

Comment: Do the database tables all have the same column names? If so, I suspect it would be faster to create a single query of the form `SELECT * FROM table1 UNION SELECT * FROM table2 UNION SELECT * ... etc etc`. Use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` if you want to ensure that any duplicate rows are kept.

Comment: Yes, They are the same table structure just with different data in each one

Answer (score 2):

Before I post my solution, I should include a quick warning that you should never use string manipulation to generate SQL queries unless it's absolutely unavoidable, and in such cases you need to be certain that you are in control of the data which is being used to format the strings and it won't contain anything that will cause the query to do something unintended.

With that said, this seems like one of those situations where you do need to use string formatting, since you cannot pass table names as parameters. Just make sure there's no way that users can alter what is contained within your list of tables.

Onto the solution. It looks like you can get your list of tables using:

```
tables = Ave.columns.tolist()
```

For my simple example, I'm going to use:

```
tables = ['table1', 'table2', 'table3']
```

Then use the following code to generate a single query:

```
query_template = 'select * from {}'
query_parts = []
for table in tables:
    query = query_template.format(table)
    query_parts.append(query)
full_query = ' union all '.join(query_parts)
```

Giving:

```
'select * from table1 union all select * from table2 union all select * from table3'
```

You can then simply execute this one query to get your results:

```
cnx = sqlite3.connect('Market_Cap.db')
df = pd.read_sql_query(full_query, cnx)
```

Then from here you should be able to set the index, convert to datetime etc, but now you only need to do these operations once rather than 300 times. I imagine the overall runtime of this should now be much faster.